# SqlCommand Select Command Aliases

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code:

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.;initial catalog=testdb;integrated security=sspi");
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("select * from (select count(studentid) from student) as student", Connection);

Connection.Open();
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I expect the query comes from the user, so I need to filter it after the the select is written my way:

```
select * from (user query) as table
```

but it throws an error:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'student'.

because some times columns must be aliased if it a function like count or avg

I need to use this way to filter the query after the user write it. Also I know where will not work after grouping and having must have an aggregation method at the SQL query...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be a comment but I think the formatting here makes it clearer.

Logically there is no difference between

```
SELECT *
FROM ({query}) AS STUDENT
```

and

```
{query}
```

So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: sometimes the users enter a sql query have a column needs to be aliased

userquery = select studentlevel,count(studentid) from student group by studentlevel

this is an expected input
I need to filter this query
using where is not workin because of the grouping I need to group after the filter
so I need to put it in this way
select * from (select select studentlevel,count(studentid) from student group by studentlevel) 
where column = value
to use the where after group by
this is what am tryng to do

Comment: @MustafaMuawiaIbrahim - ok... but the code you wrote does not help that -- so is that what you are asking -- how to solve the problem of bad user input?

Comment: it's not a bad user input ......
it's expected user input ......
i need to make it easy for the user not forcing him to alias the columns

Comment: @MustafaMuawiaIbrahim - you are asking for sql and the user is giving illegal sql -- that is bad input.  The only way to do this is make a parser for the language you want (which is not sql) and convert from that language to sql

Answer (score 0):

You just missing alias for count of students

```
select * from (select count(studentid) as CountOfStudents from student) as student
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes both in code and SQL syntax. The Error you receive is due to the fact that you have a confused query asking the count of the studednts without giving it the name, then you select this single value and try to give a name to a table... Besides, you use an ExecuteNonQuery that as its name tells executes some SQL on SQL server and does not retrieve anything, this kind of command is usually used to Execute statements to Insert or update data. The Correct code, is the following:

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.;initial 
catalog=testdb;integrated security=sspi;persist security info=true");
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("select count(studentid) AS StudentsNumber from student", Connection);

Connection.Open();
object result = Command.ExecuteScalar(); 
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: I was just testing the query .... I will use the reader ..... but the idea is:.....

 
sometimes the users enter a sql query have a column needs to be aliased userquery = select studentlevel,count(studentid) from student group by studentlevel .... this is an expected input I need to filter this query, using where is not workin because of the grouping, I need to group after the filter so I need to put it in this way select * from (select select studentlevel,count(studentid) from student group by studentlevel) where column = value to use the where after group by, this is what am tryng to do

Comment: If you want to group After the filter you can't use the Count function, because a Count function is a group function. Besides, if you want to give your user the possibility to filter data, you can't just get the count of student ID but you need to get the whole content of the fields where you want your user to be able to filter data and then count what you want and get it.